# Ionic 3: iOS infinite scroll (position top) loading data display issues

Tags: ios, arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

In my application there is a chat where if the user scrolls up, more chat messages will be loaded. I use ionic's default "infinite scroll" (position = 'top') component to detect when the user has reached the top of the page to load more messages into the array. On the browser and on android this works very well with a threshold of (50% or 550px), but on iOS (native device and emulator) I get a weird issue that can be seen through the image. [image: chat display property] The red represents the part of the screen the user sees and the black represents the total scroll length. As seen in iOS since the scroll view shoots to the top, it triggers the infinite scroll many times from one call, which is not ideal. It also creates a poor user experience with the screen jumping to the top and not being able to follow the previous messages. I've tried disabling scrolling but that did not work. iOS also does not seem to detect the infinite-scroll threshold and only triggers when at the top of the scroll-view. I also tried upgrading to WKWebView, but that did not solve this issue.

Platform Info:
ionic-angular: 3.20.0
ios platform: 4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it seems like you're probably pushing the loaded data to the end of your list rather than adding it the beginning. You want to do:

this.chatMessages = [ ...newContent, ...this.chatMessage ];

Answer (score 0):

Are you manage to solve this ? 
Mine scenario is 
1- after scroll top 
2- infinite scroll is activate and call the ionInfinite method.
3- result added to array list
4- automatic trigger scroll again
5- and repeat step 2-4 until.